# Deadlock qustions

Tags: sql, transactions, deadlock

Can someone explain to me why those are the correct answers for this deadlocking scenario? This is a quiz question on a practice test and I'm unsure why the answer I choice A is not correct and the other answers B, C and D are correct. Thank you for you time

The scenario below describes resource acquisition and locking of three transactions. Read the scenario and follow the subsequent instructions.

Transaction T1 will access and exclusively lock resource X, followed by Y

Transaction T2 will access and exclusively lock resource Y, followed by X

Transaction T3 will access and exclusively lock resource X, followed by Y

Assume that these transactions are presented to the DBMS all at the same time. Select all possible outcomes from this scenario.

Incorrectd. A deadlock can occur between T1 and T3, while T2 completes successfully.

Correct Answers:

Correct b. A deadlock can occur between T2 and T3, while T1 completes successfully.

Correct c. All three transactions can complete successfully.

Correct d. A deadlock can occur between T1 and T2, while T3 completes successfully.

Comment: See [help], point #3: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score 0):

Readup http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx and figure it out. You might surprise yourself.